# RxSwift Optimising Triggers

Tags: swift, optimization, rx-swift

I perform a task when the application enters the foreground.
I also want to perform this task as soon as my view model is initialised.

How can I write this to avoid copy and pasting the task code?
Currently the code looks like this:

```
init(dependencies: Dependencies) {
        self.dependencies = dependencies

        dependencies.apiClient.notificationsCount()
            .map { $0.value > 0 ? String($0.value) : nil }
            .bind(to: tabBadgeValue)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
        dependencies.notification.notification(for: .appWillEnterForeground)
            .map { _ in () }
            .flatMapLatest(dependencies.apiClient.notificationsCount)
            .map { $0.value > 0 ? String($0.value) : nil }
            .bind(to: tabBadgeValue)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `startWith` to emit a next event before receiving the first notification:

```
init(dependencies: Dependencies) {
    self.dependencies = dependencies

    dependencies.notification.notification(for: .appWillEnterForeground)
        .map { _ in () }
        .startWith(())
        .flatMapLatest(dependencies.apiClient.notificationsCount)
        .map { $0.value > 0 ? String($0.value) : nil }
        .bind(to: tabBadgeValue)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution for which I was searching.